# Append binary number

Tags: c++, binary

For example, if my input is 010010, bitmap should be updated to 010010. And since I have to check if the input is either '1' or '0', I have to initialize `c` to char, after the checking, append it to bitmap, but with the code below what I get is 2 instead of 010010.

How can I do this without using string or array? Thanks in advance.

e.g.

```
int bitmap;
unsigned char c;
for ( int i = 0, i < 6, ++i){
    cin >> c; //get each places one by one
    if (c != '0' && c != '1'){ //check if the input is neither '1' or '0'
                return -1;
            } else {
                  int ic = c - 48;
                  bitmap += ic; // <- this is the part I don't know how to do
                  return 0;
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

I have changed my code so that for example, if I enter 100100101, it will give me that no problem. But when I enter 010010010 for example, it will only give me 10010010(only 8 digits instead of 9)

My code is as follow:

```
unsigned char c;
int bitmap, i = 0;
        while (i < numSeats){
            cin >> c;
            if (c != '1' && c != '0'){ //check if input is neither '0' or '1'
                 return  -1;
            } else {
                int ic = c - '0';
                long long power = ONE;
                for (int j = numSeats - 1 - i; j > 0 ; --j) {
                    power *= 10;
                }
                bitmap += ic * power;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: '0' is not 0 and '1' is not 1, so you need to check if you have char '0' or '1' and then convert them to int 0 or 1.

Comment: Post [mcve]. The actual code never makes bitmap getting 2.

Comment: The conversion `c - 48` should be written as `c - ‘0’`. Hat way there are no assumptions about character encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int ic = c
```

Does not do what you think it does. As you may know, all characters (`char` type) are actually 8-bit numbers. Converting them to `int` results in the same value, but not with regard to the semantics of the digits (eg. `'0' == 48` would evaluate as `true`, while `'0' == 0` is `false`).

A possible solution to your case would look like this.

```
int bitmap = 0; // Initialize!
unsigned char c;
for ( int i = 0, i < 6, ++i){
cin >> c; //get each places one by one
if (c != '0' && c != '1'){
            return -1;
        } else {
              int ic = (c == '1') ? 1 : 0;
              // operator |= is a bitwise or (simple addition might be dangerous in this context, this operation just toggles the desired bit)
              // operator << is a bitshift - the bit that is set to 1 can be simply moved around an arbitrary number of bits like this
              bitmap |= ic << (5 - i);
              return 0;
        }
    }
```

Also, the term 'bitmap' usualy refers to an image. The word you are looking for (correct me if I'm wrong) is probably a 'bitfield'.

Comment: It should be int ic = c -48; I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    char* bitmap = new char[10];
    unsigned char c;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        cin >> c; //get each places one by one
        if (c != '0' && c != '1'){ //check if the input is neither '1' or '0'
            return -1;
        } else {
            int ic = c;
            bitmap[i] = ic;
        }
    }
    cout << bitmap;
    return 0;
}
```

This one will straight away print whatever 6 bits you want to add.

Notice the changes on the first line where the bitmap is defined and the value is updated in the else part.